# Why can't I install the package 'copula' on a Jupyter notebook when it is available on RStudio?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, install.packages

On RStudio, the command `install.packages("copula")` is successful; however, I get the following error message when doing so from within a Jupyter Notebook with an R kernel:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependency ‘gsl’


Warning message in install.packages("copula"):
“installation of package ‘gsl’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("copula"):
“installation of package ‘copula’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other, you might as well ask about windows versus macOS.  But you could always go [to the source](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=copula) which reveals a moderately long chain of dependencies.  This is recursive: you now need to check if the dependecies install.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Are the dependencies under "Reverse depends"? If so, is your suggestion to install all the dependencies before installing 'copula'?

Comment: No, revere depends is _who uses this package_ so it is the inverse, You want 'Imports' and 'LinkingTo', possibly 'Suggests'.  The easisest (but slowest) way to see where things go pear-shaped is to install those one by one. (And try to load each via `library(...)`.  But my bigger point was more meta:  your Jupyter library will be independent of your normal path, having it in one does not affect the other.